# Rellenar string con palabras

Tags: c

una pregunta rapida, soy nuevo y tengo una duda sobre las cadenas de caracteres. Puedo rellenar un char con palabras en vez de cadenas?La cuestion es que quiero hacer un bucle for en el que me vaya imprimiendo la palabra correspondiente la posicion de una variable i que va aumentando en el bucle.

char unidades[256]={ 'mg/dl', mg/100ml,... }

Gracias!

Comment: No, tienes que almacenar letra por letra si quieres múltiples palabras puedes utilizar una matriz y almacenar en cada fila una palabra pero una letra por columna.

Answer (score 4):

Una cadena de caracteres en ANSI C, no es más que un apuntador que almacena caracteres de forma "consecutiva" en memoria, es por ello que declarar un `char array[4];` es igual a declarar `char *array = NULL;`, en el sentido de que ambos son punteros, con la única diferencia en que la primera se reserva **4 bytes** de memoria para almacenar **4 caracteres ASCII**.

Esta forma (`char *array = NULL;`) declara un puntero de tipo char, pero todavía no se ha reservado memoria, para ello debes hacerlo de manera dinámica `char *array = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);`, de esta forma se reservan 4 bytes de memoria para **4 caracteres** y **un byte** para el carácter que indica el final del arreglo.

En conclusión, existe dos formas de manejar memoria en **ANSI C**, la primera forma es estática y la segunda dinámica.

**Arreglo de char* en ANSI C (estático)**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *array[4] = {"uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro"};

    for (int k=0; k < 4; k++) 
        printf("%s\n", array[k]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Arreglo de char* en ANSI C (dinámico)**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    size_t cap = 4;

    const char **array = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * cap);
    if (array != NULL) {
        array[0] = "uno";
        array[1] = "dos";
        array[2] = "tres";
        array[3] = "cuatro";

        for (int k=0; k < cap; k++)
            printf("%s", array[k]);

        free(array);
        array != NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

*Al final, en ambos casos se trabajan con arreglos multidimensionales, es decir matrices para este caso.*

Comment: char array[4] solo reserva 4 bytes, incluyendo el 0 final. Así que solo puedes introducir 3 caracteres y el cuarto sería el 0. Si metes 4 caracteres y un cero después, tienes una bonita excepción.

Comment: Gracias por la corrección @SuperG280, tienes toda la razón, edité el texto para corregir ese detalle.Saludos.